# Find all cells on a grid which is in circle?

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, shapes

I have a grid which is 100 by 100, and I have a circle. I want the circle to put a value in every cell that the circle covers. Is there a good algorithm for this ? I will be using as3 but I don't think that would be a issue.

edit.

I'm trying to find a algorithm which will return all cells within the circle and all cells which are semi in the circle / mostly in the circle (Greater than 50%). As I haven't found algorithm which does this I cannot show any code.

Comment: Hint: a point is inside a circle if the point's distance from the center is less than the circle's radius.

Comment: This is a little off-topic for Stack Overflow.  What have you tried so far?  Is there a specific problem or technical curiosity 
that you're running into?

Comment: Please clarify a few things, othrwise you might get flagged. What have you tried so far? Do you have any code? Do you want squares that the circle covers completely, or only partially? If you do these i will give you an answer asap

Comment: @MartonPallagi Sorry about that, I updated it

Comment: Okay so full coverage is easy, any square with its 4 vertices inside the circle is fully covered. Partial coverage is easy too, any square with one vertex inside the circle is partially covered. The problem is 50% coverage, since 50% coverage is only guaranteed if a square has 3 vertices inside the circle, but a square can be mostly covered if it only has 2, or even 1 vertex inside. So what you should try is something like this:

Comment: Go through the vertices inside the circle, find the squares which have 3 or 4 vertices inside. Then, check the common area of the circle and the leftover squares with 1 or 2 vertices inside, one at a time, and calculate the shared area. I think the best way to do this would be to connect the center of the circle with the intersections, calculate the area of the triangles you get, and subtract from the area of the sector.

Comment: @MartonPallagi Thanks for the help here, didn't think about using the vectors to check if the square is semi in. So I will make a square around the circle (which is the same width and height of the circle) and check if in within distance, if it not then I will check all four vectors of that square and if it 3 or 4 then it will be semi in. Thanks Again and sorry for not adding the correct information originally.

Comment: It's ok, it's not that the question was bad, it's just that it belongs more in the Math section. You could post your solution as an answer if you have figured it out, to bring it back to being as3 related.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but might be useful for anyone  (like me) looking for an answer here.

The (pseudocode) approach I took was to work out a bounding box around the circle of centre a,b radius r using two opposite corners:

```
topLeft = (x:a - r, y:b + r)
bottomRight: (x:a + r, y:b - r)
```

Then iterate over all squares within the bounding box and test if they are in the circle

```
for(x between topLeft.x and bottomRight.x){
  for(y between topLeft.y and bottomRight.y){
    if((x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 < r^2){
      // point is in circle
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use symmetry to make this more efficient as well, by only doing it for 1/4 of the grid. If we translate the system such that the center of the circle is at 0,0 then determine that the box at point (3,2) is in the circle then that means that mirror wise points in the other 3 quadrants are also covered by the circle: (-3, 2), (3,-2) and (-3, -2).

Answer (score -2):

Start at the centre of the circle.  Mark that grid square.  Now construct a spiral starting from that square, checking each grid square along the spiral and marking as appropriate.  There will be some formula for how long each new turn of the spiral will be.  When a full turn of the spiral is outside the circle you do not need to check any more grid squares.